# Sort function is changing numbers in my array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have been trying to implement an insert sort function, but it has some weird behavior. The problem happens when I am trying to only use [0,1000] and it converts all of the numbers in my array to [0,9]. If i bump the numbers above 1000, it works perfectly fine, but anything below just won' work. Any ideas why?

```
public static void insertSort(int[] array) {
    for (int a : array) {
        System.out.print(array[a] + " ");
    }
    int length = array.length;
    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        int key = array[i];
        int j = (i - 1);
        while (j > -1 && array[j] > key) {
            array[j + 1] = array[j];
            j--;
        }
        array[j + 1] = key;
    }
    for(int b:array) {
        System.out.print(array[b] + " ");
    }
}

createdArray = new int[100000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        double x = (Math.random() * 1000); // if i increase to *10000, it works fine
        createdArray[i] = (int) x;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not how loop through and print the value of an array

```
for (int a : array) {
    System.out.print(array[a] + " ");
}
```

`a` is the actual value **not** the index, so you can simply do

```
for (int a : array) {
    System.out.print(a + " ");
}
```

likewise for

```
for(int b:array) {
    System.out.print(array[b] + " ");
}
```

Comment: You'll be happy to know I just face-palmed myself. Thank you lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code with problems in it:

```
 for (int a : array) {
        System.out.print(array[a] + " ");
    }

 for(int b:array) {
        System.out.print(array[b] + " ");
    }
```

You are using the variable you are supposed to print as an **index**. You can just simply print the variable itself.

```
 for (int a : array) {
   System.out.print(a + " ");
 }

 for(int b:array) {
   System.out.print(b + " ");
 }
```